# Using memcpy with hex values

Tags: c, memcpy

I can do

```
memcpy(buffer, "\0", 1);
```

but I can't do

```
memcpy(buffer, 0x0, 1);
```

It causes segmentation fault.

Is there a way I can use hex values with memcpy without their string representation?

Comment: What is your outer problem? What are you trying to accomplish? A very specific answer to this (likely simplified) problem most likely won't help you with your real issue. (Or are you always going to deal with a single byte? If more than one, it matters how because values have to be encoded in some way to be stored in memory and there is often more than one option for how to do that.)

Comment: I think you want `memset`, not `memcpy`

Comment: The first is a `char*` pointer to a NULL-terminated string buffer, the second is a NULL pointer. Of course it will explode.

Comment: A string has a single right way to represent it in memory. But a numerical value expressed in hex can also be stored in memory any number of different ways. And how you write code to store such a value in memory depends on how you want the value expressed. For example `0x7214` can be stored in memory with the `0x72` first or the `0x14` first. Or if it's representing a signed quantity, might need to be sign extended. We need a lot more information to give you a useful suggestion for how to encode the data correctly in memory.

Comment: `memcpy` copies data from one buffer into another.  `memset` will set a series of bytes in a buffer with a given value.  It does not appear that you are intending to send in an address to a source buffer in the second argument from which to copy which leads me to believe that `memcpy` is not what you want to be using.

Comment: I also suspect in your first example, you may have intended to pass `'\0'` as the second argument, which would be more the equivalent of `0x0`, but you instead passed `"\0"` which, as tadman pointed out, is comes to a string buffer that contains the null character rather than just being the null character itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`memcpy` accepts two pointers. `"\0"` is a pointer to a string. `0x0` interpreted as a pointer is `NULL`, which is illegal to read and write from on most platforms.

The correct way to rewrite the second example would be to use a pointer:

```
int x = 0x0;
memcpy(buffer, &x, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks! The edited part of your answer was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Those are very different things.

The first

```
memcpy(buffer, "\0", 1);
```

copies 1 character of the literal string `"\0"` into `buffer`.

The second

```
memcpy(buffer, 0x0, 1);
```

attempts to copy one byte from `0`. This is the same as

```
memcpy(buffer, NULL, 1);
```

Comment: The point was not the 0x0 value, but hexadecimals in general.

Comment: It's the same issue. You have to give `memcpy` two pointers to valid memory locations. If you just give it a "random" number, whether it's in decimals or hexadecimals, it probably won't be pointing to some memory that's allocated to your program.

Comment: What I was after is a way to convert the hex value to a format that could be passed to memcpy.

Comment: @MikkoP. I have addressed that in my answer.

Comment: But how is this transformation done programmatically? The hex values I have aren't hardcoded in the code so I need to convert the on the fly.

Comment: Why would you do that? This is sounding like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.